# How to do SELECT with column name that appears twice in DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code..

```
DataFrame addressDF = sqlContext.read().parquet(addressParquetPath);
DataFrame propertyDF = sqlContext.read().parquet(propertyParquetPath);

DataFrame joinedFrame = addressDF.join(propertyDF, propertyDF.col("LOCID").equalTo(addressDF.col("locid")), "left");

joinedFrame.registerTempTable("joinedFrame");
DataFrame joinedFrameSelect = sqlContext.sql("SELECT LOCID,AddressID FROM joinedFrame");
```

in the Select LocID is listed twice, how do i pick the LocId of Address instead of property.

Can i execute select on the dataframe by column index?

Comment: You should consider using DataFrame API to do select, e.g. `joinedFrame.select("LOCID", "AddressID")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually rename the column -- you can either try:

```
...join(propertyDF.withColumnRenamed("LocID", "LocID_R"), ...
```

Or if you want to change all of the column names for a `DataFrame` in one go -- such as add an `_R` for "right" to every name -- you can try this:

```
df.toDF(df.columns.map(_ + "_R"):_*)
```

This is useful when you are joining a `DataFrame` back onto itself.