# Error: Resolved attributes missing in join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to perform a `join` of two tables with a relatively complex join condition (using greater than/smaller than in the join conditions). This works fine, but breaks down as soon as I add a `fillna` command before the join.

The code looks something like this:

```
join_cond = [
    df_a.col1 == df_b.colx,
    df_a.col2 == df_b.coly,
    df_a.col3 >= df_b.colz
]

df = (
    df_a
    .fillna('NA', subset=['col1'])
    .join(df_b, join_cond, 'left')
)
```

This results in an error like this:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) **col1#4765** missing from **col1#6488**,col2#4766,col3#4768,colx#4823,coly#4830,colz#4764 in operator !Join LeftOuter, (((**col1#4765** = colx#4823) && (col2#4766 = coly#4830)) && (col3#4768 >= colz#4764)). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: col1. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.

It looks like spark no longer recognizes `col1` after performing the `fillna`. (The error does not come up if I comment that out.) The problem is that I do need that statement. (And in general I've simplified this example a lot.)

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248652/cleanest-most-efficient-syntax-to-perform-dataframe-self-join-in-spark), but these answers do not work for me. Specifically, using `.alias('a')` after the `fillna` doesn't work because then spark does not recognize the `a` in the join condition.

Could someone:

- Explain exactly why this is happening and how I can avoid it in the future?
- Advise me on a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So many modified columns and cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is happening?

In order to "replace" empty values, a new dataframe is created that contains new columns. These new columns have the same names like the old ones but are effectively completely new Spark objects. In the [Scala code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/60f485671a07a93ae8a8506ed2c0999cfe6ded7b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.scala#L503) you can see that the "changed" columns are newly created ones while the original columns are [dropped](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/60f485671a07a93ae8a8506ed2c0999cfe6ded7b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.scala#L532).

A way to see this effect is to call [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain) on the dataframe before and after replacing the empty values:

```python
df_a.explain()
```

prints

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [_1#0L AS col1#6L, _2#1L AS col2#7L, _3#2L AS col3#8L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[_1#0L,_2#1L,_3#2L]
```

while

```python
df_a.fillna(42, subset=['col1']).explain()
```

prints

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [coalesce(_1#0L, 42) AS col1#27L, _2#1L AS col2#7L, _3#2L AS col3#8L]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[_1#0L,_2#1L,_3#2L]
```

Both plans contain a column called `col1`, but in the first case the internal representation is called `col1#6L` while the second one is called `col1#27L`.

When the join condition `df_a.col1 == df_b.colx` now is associated with the column `col1#6L` the join will fail if only the column `col1#27L` is part of the left table.

#### How can the problem be solved?

The obvious way would be to move the `fillna` operation before the definition of the join condition:

```python
df_a = df_a.fillna('NA', subset=['col1'])
join_cond = [
    df_a.col1 == df_b.colx,
[...]
```

If this is not possible or wanted you can change the join condition. Instead of using a column from the dataframe (`df_a.col1`) you can use a column that is not associated with any dataframe by using the [col](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col) function. This column works only based on its name and therefore ignores when the column is replaced in the dataframe:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
join_cond = [
    F.col("col1") == df_b.colx,
    df_a.col2 == df_b.coly,
    df_a.col3 >= df_b.colz
]
```

The downside of this second approach is that the column names in both tables must be unique.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you. This clarifies a lot of what's going on under the hood.