# Find nearest Timestamp on another column and add value in a new column PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, timestamp

I have a merged DataFrame with two TimeStamp columns. I want to find the nearest (forward) TimeStamp (Timestamp1 -> Timestamp2) and take the value asociated and add it in a new column.

```
TimeStamp1                Value1     TimeStamp2               Value2
2021-11-01T01:55:29.473   131        2021-11-01T01:55:28.205  A
2021-11-01T01:55:30.474   3          2021-11-01T01:55:31.205  B
2021-11-01T05:01:55.247   195        2021-11-01T03:44:14.208  C
2021-11-01T05:01:56.247   67         2021-11-01T05:41:56.205  D
2021-11-01T09:41:30.264   131        2021-11-01T09:41:29.405  E
2021-11-01T09:41:32.264   67         2021-11-01T09:41:35.205  F
```

Expected output:

```
TimeStamp1                Value1     Value 2 
2021-11-01T01:55:29.473   131        B
2021-11-01T01:55:30.474   3          B
2021-11-01T05:01:55.247   195        D
2021-11-01T05:01:56.247   67         D
2021-11-01T09:41:30.264   131        F
2021-11-01T09:41:32.264   67         F
```

Im working with PySpark, i checked some ways to do it but in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tranformation you are looking for can be achieved in two steps:

1. Generate all posible combinations where `df["TimeStamp2"] >= df[TimeStamp1"]` using a [`self join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248652/cleanest-most-efficient-syntax-to-perform-dataframe-self-join-in-spark). This forms our `candidate_df`.
2. We prune the `candidate_df` to retrieve the expected rows by finding the row containing the minimum `TimeStamp2` across rows containing for `TimeStamp1`. We do this my partitioning the `candidate_df` by `TimeStamp1` then ordering by `TimeStamp2` ascending and returning the first row.

> If you have threshold for the "maximum nearness" (i.e) maximum difference between `TimeStamp1` and `nearest TimeStamp2`,  then the solution can be optimized to reduce size of `candidate_df`.

## Working Example

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T01:55:29.473", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 131, datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T01:55:28.205", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "A"),
(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T01:55:30.474", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 3,   datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T01:55:31.205", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "B"),
(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T05:01:55.247", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 195, datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T03:44:14.208", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "C"),
(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T05:01:56.247", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 67,  datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T05:41:56.205", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "D"),
(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T09:41:30.264", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 131, datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T09:41:29.405", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "E"),
(datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T09:41:32.264", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), 67,  datetime.strptime("2021-11-01T09:41:35.205", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"), "F"),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("TimeStamp1", "Value1", "TimeStamp2", "Value2",))

candidate_df = df.alias("l").join(df.alias("r"), F.col("r.TimeStamp2") >= F.col("l.TimeStamp1"))\
                 .selectExpr("l.TimeStamp1 as TimeStamp1", 
                             "l.Value1 as Value1", 
                             "r.TimeStamp2 as TimeStamp2", 
                             "r.Value2 as Value2")

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("TimeStamp1").orderBy("TimeStamp2")

candidate_df.withColumn("rn" ,F.row_number().over(window_spec))\
            .filter(F.col("rn") == 1)\
            .drop("rn", "TimeStamp2")\
            .show(200, False)
```

### Output

```
+-----------------------+------+------+
|TimeStamp1             |Value1|Value2|
+-----------------------+------+------+
|2021-11-01 01:55:29.473|131   |B     |
|2021-11-01 01:55:30.474|3     |B     |
|2021-11-01 05:01:55.247|195   |D     |
|2021-11-01 05:01:56.247|67    |D     |
|2021-11-01 09:41:30.264|131   |F     |
|2021-11-01 09:41:32.264|67    |F     |
+-----------------------+------+------+
```

Comment: 10/10, Thank you so much!